# How to add cross origin url value from application.properties file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

In Spring Boot application, how to add cross origin url value from application.properties file?

```
@Value("${url.cross-origin}")
public static String url_value;


@CrossOrigin(origins = url_value)
@GetMapping("/all")
WhatEverFunction ...
```

However, I am getting an error as "Attribute value must be constant".

I have **application-dev.properties** file where I have the url value as **url.cross-origin**

Please help.